# Algorithm to figure out if a list of words form a word square

Tags: algorithm

Apparently this was a question that was asked to a friend of mine from Google. The question is, given four 4-lettered words, determine if they form a word square. Then, expand it so it can be solved for any n n-letter words. An example of a word square would be:

```
C A T S
A B E O
T E L M
S O M E
```

The quickest way we could think of was O(n!) for trying out all possible permutations of word configurations, then O(n) to check if it forms a word square, which can be done by checking if one side of the diagonals equals the other.

Comment: Make a string by iterating through normally. Make another string by iterating through the other way. Compare the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an algorithm that you would then use to make a program. This would be very easy to make in a program, but obviously if a person was able to draw it out, he would be able to quickly see if it does. If you like, I could write you a java program that will do this.)

1. I would make a 2D Array of the first letters of each word being in the first column, and the first row is made up of the first word.

   ```
   C A T S
   A B E O
   T E L M
   S O M E
   ```
2. Then check to see if the first column equals the first word, the second column equals the second word, and so on. (Since the first row literally is the first word, checking to see if the first column equals the first word will basically check to see if the first row equals the first column.)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simplistic approach would be to form a multiset of all the first letters of each word, and then search for a word that contain the exact same letters and letter counts as the multiset of first letters. If a match is found, we remove the word from consideration. Next, we look for a word whose suffix (beginning at the second letter) matches the multiset of second letters of remaining words. If a match is found, we remove it, and then check third letters, and so forth.

Here's a Python implementation that makes use of the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in place of a multiset.

```py
from collections import Counter

def word_square(words):
    words = list(words)
    n = len(words)
    assert all(len(w) == n for w in words)

    result = []

    for i in range(n):
        letters = Counter(w[i] for w in words)
        match = next((w for w in words if Counter(w[i:]) == letters), None)

        if not match:
            return None

        words.remove(match)
        result.append(match)

    return result
```

This solution is, if I not mistaken, is `O(n^3)`, which isn't great, but it's an improvement over `O(n!)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way I can think of:

```
const validWordSquare = (words) => {
  if(words.length > 0) {
    let firstRow = words[0]
    if(firstRow.length !== words.length) {
      return false
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < firstRow.length; i++) {
      let verticalWord = ''
      for(let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        verticalWord += words[j][i]
      }
      if(verticalWord !== words[i]) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a matrix transpose question. So if the original matrix and its transpose are equal then it forms a word square,

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. You are not given the *square*, only the *words*.